# Login into my deployed Umbraco back office is causing "An error has occurred.". How do I find out what is wrong?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, umbraco, azure-sql-database, umbraco7

I have deployed my Umbraco installation by using Visual Studio and the regarding nuget package version 7.4.1 and I am using Azure DB as a back-end. When I try to login I get the following message:

[image]

The logs in the folder "/site/wwwroot/App_Data/Logs/" do not show anything. Using http or https does not make any difference.

When I start Umbraco from within Visual Studio (connected to my Azure DB back-end) in debug mode the login works perfectly:

[image]

How can I find out what the issue is?

Comment: Does the front end of the site load (in other words, is it just that the back office doesn't let you log in)?

Comment: Have you enabled diagnostic logging? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting to the backend with [Open Live Writer](http://openlivewriter.org/) helped me to unveil a detailed error message. By mistake I have deleted one of the caching folders (App_Data\TEMP\PluginCache).